# jekyll - filter to remove trailing slash from post.url

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Jekyll generates post urls with a trailing slash. I want to remove this trailing slash from all urls, so I'm creating a Liquid filter "remove_trailing_slash" that I would like to use in my templates like this:

```html
<a class="blog-article" href="{{ post.url | remove_trailing_slash }}">
```

Here is the content of my plugin (`_plugins/remove_trailing_slash.rb`):

```rb
module Jekyll
  module RemoveTrailingSlash

    def remove_trailing_slash(url)
      if url[-1] == '/'
        url[0..-2]
      else
        url
      end
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::RemoveTrailingSlash)
```

### What I expect

```html
<a class="blog-article" href="/path/to/post">
```

### What I get

```html
<a class="blog-article" href="/path/to/post/">
```

It appears my filter is not doing anything.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have tested the code and it works fine. Are you sure there is only a single trailing slash and not multiple?

Comment: Indeed, it works now. I think it is due to my local dev environment: i had to kill and restart jekyll (instead of livereloading). Thanks for taking the time to check this!

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer, I don't know ruby, can you make a variant of `{{ page.url }}`, because when using `permalink: pretty`, there will be a slash at the end of `{{ page.url }}`

**tips**❗ The current ruby block is not valid for `{{ page.url }}`

---

Sorry, I correct my answer, although he **did not remove** the slash from `page.url`, he took effect (because I restarted jekyll serve).
Use case: used to detect the navigation page in the navigation page if it is equal to `page.url`, add an `active` class

**Correct code example** ✔️

```
{% for item in site.data.navigation.nav %}
<a href="{{ item.link }}" class="nav-link {% assign No_slash = page.url | remove_trailing_slash %}{% if item.link == No_slash %}active{% endif %}">{{ item.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**Error code example** ❌

```
{% for item in site.data.navigation.nav %}
<a href="{{ item.link }}" class="nav-link {% if item.link == page.url | remove_trailing_slash %}active{% endif %}">{{ item.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```